# How I get a list of the online users in Yii2?

Tags: yii2, yii2-advanced-app, yii2-model, yii2-user

How do I get the list of the online users in yii2? I want to see who is onlone and who signed out.

Answer (score 0):

I was the same problem recently and I finished saving a timestamp to any login and logout action of each user in a table, because I didn't find any "native" solution.
You could solve your problem with a couple of lines as a first approach.
Depending on of your auth system maybe there are some better solution.